# Running JavaScript from the windows command prompt

Tags: javascript, command-line, cmd

I wrote the following JavaScipt code which converts a binary number into a decimal number:

```
(function bin_dec(num) {
  var x = num;
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    result += eval(x[x.length - i] * 2^i);
  }
  return result;
})()
```

I want to be able to run this code from the command-line. The filename is **converter.js** and I am running the command prompt window in the same directory as the file. I am trying to run this code using `01001100` as the function argument. Here are my attempts:

```
$ converter.js 01001100
```

and

```
$ converter.js -01001100
```

and

```
$ converter.js bin_dec(01001100)
```

But unfortunately, neither of these works. Can somebody please point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have an IIFE ... `num` argument will always be `undefined` because of how you've written the IIFE ... that aside ... running javascript on the command line ... how do you propose this to work? do you get any errors when you do that? I'm guessing you are running linux, right

Comment: But.. have you any tool that parses and executes JS from the command line? Like NodeJS or similar? Besides that, you have an IIFE, so no function declaration is present (ie `bin_dec` is not accessible from outside). Plus you don't need `eval`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) if you haven't done so yet.

2) Change your `converter.js` file like this:

```
function bin_dec(num) {
  return parseInt(num, 2);
}

console.log(bin_dec(process.argv[2]));
```

3) Open a new command prompt in the folder where your script is and run

```
$ node converter.js 01001100
```

Comment: Node.js console.log() is surprisingly rich. Unpacks and colorizes objects. And Unicode works! The scary prompt during Node.js install about compiling C/C++ appears to be optional. Basic stuff works without checking that box. Wish I knew [what is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361043/673991) though...

Answer (score 4):

In nodejs, assuming that you already have it installed since you are trying to run javascript from cmd, you will have to refer to the `process.argv` array in order to get the arguments passed in the command line.

So your code will need to look like this:

```
(function bin_dec(num) {
  var x = num;
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    result += eval(x[x.length - i] * 2^i);
  }
  return result;
})(process.argv[2])
```

Notice `process.argv[2]` that is passed to the function. That will make the first argument available as the `num` variable inside your function.

You may also add a `console.log` somewhere if you want to have messages displayed on the screen, since the return statement will not print messages.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running on Windows, You can call it like this:

```
(function bin_dec() {
  var x = WScript.arguments(0);
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    result += eval(x[x.length - i] * 2^i);
  }
  return result;
})()
```

Where all parameters passed into the function are stored in `WScript.arguments`.

However, this will not output the `return` value to the command prompt, so you may want to test it out with this `.js` file:

```
(function ShowAlert() {
  var x = WScript.arguments(0);
  WScript.ECho(x);
})()
```

See these links for more details:

[MSDN - Arguments Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx)

[SS64 - WScript Arguments](http://ss64.com/vb/arguments.html)

[SS64 - VBScript Command line arguments](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to know that, few basic functions like `console` or `return` statements will not work in CLI.

If you're using windows, then use `'WScript.echo'` which is similar to `console.log` and while executing the file make sure you do it this way like

`Cscript.exe yourpath input_params` for example `Cscript.exe converter.js 01001100`

So your code should be

```
(function bin_dec() {
    var x = WScript.arguments(0);
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        result += eval(x[x.length - i] * 2^i);
    }
    WScript.echo(result);
})();
```

and to run it should be

```
Cscript.exe converter.js 01001100
```

hope this helps you! For more information on CLI methods visit the following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2795740w(v=vs.84).aspx