# Windows script error when executing globally installed project

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, typescript, npm

I just installed my project globally and I'm getting a windows script host error:

### [image]

How do I fix this?

This is my javascript code.

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); //line 38
```

I am using typescript so this is a javascript build from the original typescript file. Line 38 is actually before the 1st line in the typescript file so it doesn't even exist in the original typescript file.

Thank you.

Comment: That is from you trying to execute a js file with the default Windows OS file association, which wont run it as a nodejs script

Comment: I am trying to run `instapostwouter` through my cmd prompt because I installed my project globally.

Comment: No, now it gives me the same error but with line 1 char 1, unknown character. I believe a shebang is not used in windows

Answer (score 0):

If you have node installed, I think you can try execute your script file from command prompt, with something like:

```
node <YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH_AND_FILENAME_WITH_EXTENSION_HERE>
```

I've found this in 
[Running JavaScript from the windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777585/running-javascript-from-the-windows-command-prompt)

Credits to user GOTO 0.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That would probably work but is not what I want. I want to be able to run the script by running `instapostwouter` in a commandprompt