# Why do I need Visual Studio and C++ to install node modules

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, vue.js, npm, node-gyp

Recently I have upgraded my node version to 14+ from 10+ in a Vue.Js app. But It was giving me some error and asking to install Visual Studio including C++. When I installed VS with C++. It started working great. But after that whenever I do a fresh "npm install" It requires C++. It doesn't seem normal. What is the relation between node and C++. I thing there is something what I am missing. If anyone know the solution please let me know...

**I have mentioned where the app is using C++ down bellow.**

```
> node-zopfli-es@1.0.4 install G:\PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\node-zopfli-es

> node-gyp rebuild


G:\PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\node-zopfli-es>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

zopfli-binding.cc

zopflipng.cc

zopflipng_lib.cc

lodepng.cpp

......
```

Comment: Some modules are written in C++, and needs a C++ compiler to be built.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite normal with certain types of node.js packages. A lot packages have binary dependencies to improve performance (or just to integrate with a pre-existing library like zopfli). Instead of the project maintainers distributing a ton of different binaries for different architectures and versions of operating systems they tend to supply the source and let it be built when installed.

This is usually handled by [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) which is also featured in your build log but it in turn requires the correct build tools to be available on the system, in most cases a C/C++ compiler and in quite a few cases Python as well.

For older versions of node.js you could use the [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools)-package to install the needed dependencies (you won't need a full Visual Studio for example, just the build tools) but in newer versions of the nodejs installer (for Windows at least) this is an option when installing.

[image: Node.js setup showing the page on which native modules tools can be selected]

If you missed that setting when installing you can still use the above package to install them.

Comment: So there is no option to get rid of it! When I share the code with my friend he also need to install Visual Studio which requires 10GB of space. I must need to solve the problem

Comment: As I said, you don't need the full Visual Studio. The build tools are much smaller if you just install the required stuff using the node installer. Another option would of course be to get rid of the dependencies that need this if you don't need them. In your case at least `node-zopfli-es` which is essentially just a fancy compression utility.

Comment: Oo. Ok bro thank you..

Comment: Would be nice to know: what node.js functionality is lost by NOT compiling these extra modules?

Comment: For built-in node.js functionally nothing will be lost, for installed npm packges it could be anything. Some packages use compiled binaries to increase performance but have their own fallback implementations that does the same thing but slower. Other packages are merely an API layer on top of a native package and won't work at all. It all depends on the specific package installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem and had to install Visual Studio 2019 and Python for the project to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).